# Perl WWW::Mechanize - parsing HTML into a basic report

Tags: arrays, perl, report, nested-loops, www-mechanize

I have a script that downlaods a web page and then parses that down to 
a list of URLs like this

```
<A HREF="wonk?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=20193&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>26165</B></A>
<A HREF="wonk?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22163&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>29327</B></A>
<A HREF="wonk?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22216&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>29416</B></A>
<A HREF="wonk?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId=22238&Template=view&TableId=1023"><B>29450</B></A>
```

I further strip them down and load the ticket URLs into array `@url_list` and then extract some information from them

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP;

my $username = 'casper';
my $password = 'casper';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get('http://ticketmaster/wonk.dll?ReportPage&Template=reports%2Flist&TableId=1023&Target=Query&QueryName=-6&SolutionId=8') || die "can't reach the website $!";
$mech->form_name('theform');
$mech->field('ttAuthUID' => $username);
$mech->field('ttAuthPWD' => $password);
$mech->click('Action');

print $mech->save_content(raw_teamtrack);

open(my $webpage, "<", "raw_teamtrack") || die "cannot open up the out file $!";

while (<$webpage>) {
  chomp;
  $link = $_;
  if ($link =~ /<A HREF=\"(wonk.dll\?IssuePage&SolutionId=8&RecordId.*)"/) {
    push(@url_list, $1);
  }
}

foreach $url (@url_list) {
  use WWW::Mechanize;
  use LWP;
  my $username = 'casper';
  my $password = 'casper';

  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  $mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
  $mech->get("http://ticketmaster/$url")
      || die "cannot load the ticket page $!";
  $mech->form_name('theform');
  $mech->field('ttAuthUID' => $username);
  $mech->field('ttAuthPWD' => $password);
  $mech->click('Action');
  print $mech->save_content(raw_ticket);
  open(my $ticketpage, "<", "raw_ticket")
      || die "cannot open up the out file $!";

  while (<$ticketpage>) {
    chomp;
    if (/<B>Item\sId:\s+?<\/B>(\d{5})/) {
      $Item_number = $1;
    }
    elsif (/<B>Owner:\s<\/B>(.*)<BR>/) {
      $Owner = $1;
    }
    else {
      $ticket_title =~ /<B>Title:\s<\/B>(.*)/;
      print "$Item_number   $Owner    $ticket_title\n";
      sleep 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it prints out only the Item Number and the Owner fields; it does not print out the ticket title.

Also, it prints out the information once for each iterations - for every HTML line in the ticket it downloads.

This happens to me all the time: I usually have to move the loop out of the parenthesis. That solves it, but but from a fundamental perspective I don't understand why moving it to the outside of the loop fixes it. Why is printing out for each line of HTML where it is now?

I also do not understand why `$owner` is not printed out. Is there something going on with the `else`? Should I use another `if` statement?

```
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
26165   George Glass
29327   George Glass
29327   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29450   Jimmy Jack
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee  
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee
29753   Herley Lee
```

the regexes are good.

```
bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/raw_ticket | perl -nle 'print /<B>Item\sId:\s+?<\/B>(\d{5})/' | sort -u
29871

 bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/raw_ticket | perl -nle 'print /<B>Owner:\s<\/B>(.*)<BR>/' | sort -u
Jimmy Jack
bash-3.00$

bash-3.00$  cat /tmp/raw_ticket | perl -nle 'print /<B>Title:\s<\/B>(.*)/' | sort -u
Trade Capture Prod Shadow - Install software on ushs2 - 11/15/13
bash-3.00$
```

I could not append the HTML code that I am trying to break down here as it is HTML and was not formatting please check [this pastebucket](http://pastebucket.com/22718).

Comment: Without seeing the exact input you're processing, it's difficult to help. In your last code block, you tested your regexes using a file; please post the contents of that file instead of a bunch of WWW::Mechanize code that is probably not related to your real issue. If you create a simple, self-contained example, it will be much easier to debug and you will probably get an answer faster (if you don't find it yourself in the process).

Comment: I have tidied your Perl code so that it is a little more readable, but please add `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program and fix the errors that you get from that. It isn't fair to expect help from others when you haven't used the basic tools that Perl provides.

Comment: You have replicated a lot of your code within the `for` loop, including the `use` statements and setting up your username and password variables. It should be clear that this doesn't need doing more than once, and your approach looks more like guesswork than clear thinking.

Comment: Is the data that you have posted on `pastebucket` the contents of `raw_teamtrack`?

Comment: I have had to vote to close your question. If you can't provide a program that we can run and see the problem that you're seeing then we can't really help.

Comment: @Borodin - hey  - thanks for looking at this  - i took ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggestion and put some more time in to figuring out what is wrong withthe bottom foreachloop. I took it out of the while loop. Yeah - about the replication of the code -i had trouble getting it to work and ended up replicating the whole code. I am going to selectively take things out and continue to run it.  i am self taught and you can definetly see the holes in my learning.

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking for help to fix this code. You have assembled it from guesses, and that is *never* the right way to put a program together. You should be able to explain the behaviour and purpose of every line, and ultimately every character, in your code. You can't just add bits and poke it until it's right, as if it was Play-Doh.

Comment: @Borodin You say not to "*add bits and poke until it's right*", but that is exactly how I learned to program. Of course now I don't usually have to do that. (I do work that way when trying to process ad-hoc files, as it is almost impossible to write it any other way.) I think how you stated your opinion was a bit harsh, even if I do agree to some extent. It is quite difficult to know the *right way* to program, if you don't even know the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @BradGilbert: Thank you for your comment. Yes, when you are trying to understand the beast, you can poke it and see what it spews. But that shouldn't be the condition of code that you are asking for help with. You should already have bucketsful of spew that lead you to a *judged* solution that doesn't quite work. You should be misunderstanding a black-box call, or forgetting timing considerations in a parallel context, or ... etc. But *not* misunderstanding the language you are using to program.

Comment: @Borodin - If you want to sit up in your ivory tower and take pot shots at my scripts - fine.  But if you love the Perl language as much as I do, you should understand something. You can complain about people like me all you want but I am the guy keeping this language alive - not you. Because I work for a living and by working with Perl, I am keeping it viable and alive. You're an expert but your attitude toward new adherents is driving them to nicer languages like Python. Keep it up Borodin and one day all Perl code will be clean, and just like Latin - clean and dead, only used in academics.

Comment: I hoped my comments would be read as incentives to improve all of your your programming. I doubt very much that you are keeping Perl alive, because it doesn't look like you have the hang of it at all. I am pretty sure your biggest mistake is that you are sticking to writing far too much code before you start debugging. Six or eight lines of Perl is plenty to make sure that your vestigial program is working. That is why it is so much easier to write software from scratch than to maintain existing code: you have to absorb and understand pretty much the *entire thing* before you can get started.

Comment: @Borodin - As for keeping the language alive - I work on Wall Street, I am not a scientist, but I am trained to understand trends. The younger initiates don't want anything to do with Perl.  Python is easy and they don't get flamed when they ask a python question online. In terms of my organization I working to keeping this a Perl shop. I am keeping Perl alive. But as an expert, by tearing people who are not on your level apart in forums - you are not helping keep Perl alive, you are driving people away. If beginners bother you maybe don't comment on beginners code. Pick on someone your own si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its the way that you are pattern matching with if statements and assigning a variable $1 (the last regex check/assign in your code is wrong). The following works on the test data for one example (so the ticket title will at least be printed, not sure about the loop without a set of URLs).

So I would match like this...

```
use strict;
use warnings; # always use these at top
```

....

```
my $Item_number;
my $Owner;
my $ticket_title;

while (<$webpage>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp;
    $line =~ /<B>Item\sId:\s+?<\/B>(\d{5})/ and $Item_number = $1;
    $line =~ /<B>Owner:\s<\/B>(.*)<BR>/ and $Owner = $1;
    $line =~ /<B>Title:\s<\/B>(.*)/ and $ticket_title = $1;
}
print "$Item_number   $Owner    $ticket_title\n";
```

There's a lot of other issues in the code, but just trying to isolate where I suspect the problem is. When you just do one regex to test, it will work fine, so the regex is ok in isolation. Its when you are combining multiple regexes one after the other is inconsistant.

Just to clarify the way it works, the 'and' is like a shortcut so makes the assignment only be executed if the regex is true in this case.

Comment: Hey - thanks this was really what i was looking for - suggestion on better form.